# How to make dataframe from list of list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have  searched but till not able to figure out how to make data frame from below:

```
0       ([179, 142, 176, 177, 176, 180, 180, 180, 180,...
1       ([353, 314, 349, 349, 344, 359, 359, 359, 359,...
2       ([535, 504, 535, 535, 535, 540, 540, 540, 540,...
3       ([711, 664, 703, 703, 703, 721, 721, 721, 721,...
4       ([850, 810, 822, 822, 842, 857, 857, 857, 857,.
```

below is how single data looks

```
([179, 142, 176],
 ['Qtr- Oct-20','Qtr- Oct-20','Qtr- Oct-20',],
 ['High','Low','Close'],
 [43.8, 26.05,33.1])
```

what i want is

```
      0  1           2               3
0   179 Qtr- Oct-20 High            43.8
1   142 Qtr- Oct-20 Low             26.05
2   176 Qtr- Oct-20 High_Volume     1123132
3   177 Qtr- Oct-20 High_Delivery   42499
```

what i am getting

```
      0
0   ([179, 142, 176, 177, 176, 180, 180, 180, 180,...
1   ([353, 314, 349, 349, 344, 359, 359, 359, 359,...
2   ([535, 504, 535, 535, 535, 540, 540, 540, 540,...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) + [`pd.Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html):

```
pd.DataFrame(df['col'].tolist()).apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
     0            1      2      3
0  179  Qtr- Oct-20   High   43.8
1  142  Qtr- Oct-20    Low  26.05
2  176  Qtr- Oct-20  Close   33.1
```

Note: `df['col']` is the column in the dataframe which contains list of lists.